# Send Multipart Form from PHP with Guzzle

Tags: php, api, guzzle

I'm trying to create a multipart form for upload file in my API.
According the docs of guzzle :

```php
\\$data = picture of form
\\$uri = Endpoint in my API
$this->client->post($uri, [
     'multipart' => [
        [
          'name' => 'picture',
          'contents' => file_get_contents($data),
        ]
      ],
      'headers' => $headers
]);
```

When I'm using Insomnia or Postman : 
[image]

I'm not understand why it not working in Guzzle.

Comment: What's the error or issue you're having?

Comment: Guzzle doesn't send the multipart with the field picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$file = new File($data->getPathname());
        $tmp_picture_path = Storage::putFile("temp_dir", $file);
        $tmp_picture = Storage::readStream($tmp_picture_path);
        $response = $this->client->post(
            $uri,
            [
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'picture',
                        'contents' => $tmp_picture,
                        'filename' => "avatar." . $data->getClientOriginalExtension()
                    ]
                ],
                'headers' => $headers
            ]
        );
        Storage::delete($tmp_picture_path);
```

Just save locally the file and read the stream dor send it properly.